# :before psuedo-class works locally but not on remote server

Tags: css, html-table, pseudo-class

I have a `:before` pseudo-class that sets some styles on a `<td>` element. Everything is rendering correctly in my local environment, but when I upload to the server the :before class is not attached to the  element at all. It doesn't appear in the chrome dev tools when inspected, whereas on my local environment it does.

Correct in my local env (`<td>` has `:before` attached):

[image: Correct in my local env:]

Incorrect on remote server (`<td>` does NOT have `:before` attached):

[image: Incorrect on remote server:]

I note that the `:before` class is applied to both `<tr>` elements that wrap the `<td>`, so could be something to do with nesting the pseudo-classes? But I'm at a loss as to why this would work locally and not on the remote server.

I am using SCSS to compile the css into one master.css file and I have checked that the files are the same, and that the PHP versions on my local env and the remote server match. If anyone has any ideas on how to get the `:before` pseudo-class and related styles to work on the server, that would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: please add your scss & markup as well as any details about how the scss is turned into css that might help people to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the `:before` psuedo-class and related styles working on the server by adding `content: ""` to the styles. For reasons I don't understand, the local version was able to cope without this but the server wasn't.